# ActivatedRoute Params Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to obtain the data of each record through ActivatedRouted, I have managed to obtain the ID of each one but I can not get the other data. Any ideas?

My stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-params

**services.ts**

```
getProductos() {

this.productos = [
  {
    id: 'lomoFino',
    titulo: 'Lomo fino',
    descripcion: 'Es la pieza más fina de la res, de textura tierna.',
    recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Plancha'],
    ubicacion: 'Lomo',
  },
  {
    id: 'colitaCuadril',
    titulo: 'Colita de cuadril',
    descripcion: 'Es un corte triangular y ligeramente marmoleado.',
    recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Horno'],
    ubicacion: 'Trasera',
  },
  {
    id: 'asadoCuadrado',
    titulo: 'Asado cuadrado',
    descripcion: 'Corte fibroso, de sabor agradable.',
    recomendaciones: ['Guisos', 'Freir', 'Plancha'],
    ubicacion: 'Entrepierna',
  }
]

return this.productos
}
```

productos.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productos = this.ps.getProductos();
}
```

productos.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos">
  <a [routerLink]="['/productos', producto.id]">{{ producto.titulo }}</a>
</div>
```

producto-detalle.component.ts

```
constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  this.titulo = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('titulo')
  this.descripcion = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('descripcion')
}
```

producto-detalle.component.html

```
ID: {{ id }}<br>
Título: {{ titulo }}<br>
Descripción: {{ descripcion }}<br>
```

How can I get `titulo` and`descripcion` for example.

Comment: You are sending only the ID as parameter of the route: `[routerLink]="['/productos', producto.id]`. Try to use it to get the rest of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ActivatedRoute`'s resolver(see [Resolve: pre-fetching component data](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)). This way, your producto data will be pre-fetched to the `ActivatedRoute`'s
`data` object and be available under `activatedRoute.snapshot.data`. Now you can use it in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const producto = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.producto;

  this.id = producto.id;
  this.titulo = producto.titulo;
  this.descripcion = producto.descripcion;
}
```

Your router config should be updated with resolver:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProductosComponent },
  { 
    path: 'productos/:id', 
    component: ProductoDetalleComponent,
    resolve: {
      producto: ProductoResolver
    }
  },
];
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-params-x18xcw?file=src/app/producto-detalle/producto-detalle.component.ts)

[Crisis center code](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/content/examples/router/src/app/crisis-center)

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more complete approach. I suppose there are advantages in handling data with Resolve.

Comment: every time I update the url for example `localhost:4200/productos/lomoFino` I get a small error in my local application` TypeError: Can not read property 'find' of undefined` I do not understand why

Comment: `getProducto<Producto>(id) { return of(this.productos.find(p => p.id === id)); }` In this piece of code I get an error: `TypeError: Can not read property 'find' of undefined` when I reload the page. Any idea?

Comment: @PacoZevallos, in real application products will be probably fetched asynchronously from the server, and your service will probably have at least 2 asynchronous methods 'getProductos()' and 'getProducot(id)'. I updated my stackblitz, so it fakes those methods using `of()` function, Now you should not have mentioned error. Please see my updated stackblitz, changed files are `productos.server.ts`, `productos/productos.component.ts` and `productos/productos.component.html`

Comment: This?: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-params-x18xcw

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-params-x18xcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproductos.service.ts

Comment: extraordinary! now it works well! your help has really been very valuable, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the data to the params list. First update the app.router.ts with the following code:

```
{ path: 'productos/:id/:titulo/:description', component: ProductoDetalleComponent }
```

Update the code at productos.component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/productos', producto.id,producto.titulo,producto.descripcion]">
```

Here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-params-wbnqsv?file=src/app/productos/productos.component.html)

Comment: Thanks this works, although if I have a lot of data for each record it becomes somewhat complicated to manage and above all to preserve the integrity of the URL? thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in service.ts like

```
getproduct(id:int) {
//code to return product based 
on id.
}
```

which will accept an id and gives you back the product based on the id.
How to write code for filtering object? See below link.
https://expertcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/26/typescript-filter-object-array-with-multiple-conditions/

Now this is your flow..
1. From activated route pull out the id.
2. In producto-detalle.component.ts from ngOninit call the getproduct(id) method from service.ts. (Remember to inject the service)
3.Assign  id ,titulo,descripcion from the product received from getproduct(id) and display it on the html .